# C++ reading buffer size

Tags: c++, file-io, buffer

Suppose that this file is 2 and 1/2 blocks long, with block size of 1024.

```
aBlock = 1024;
char* buffer = new char[aBlock];
while (!myFile.eof()) {
    myFile.read(buffer,aBlock);
    //do more stuff
}
```

The third time it reads, it is going to write half of the buffer, leaving the other half with invalid data. Is there a way to know how many bytes did it actually write to the buffer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[istream::gcount](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/gcount/) returns the number of bytes read by the previous read.

Comment: Quoting from your link: "The unformatted input operations that modify the value returned by this function are those performed by the following member functions: get, getline, ignore, peek, read, readsome, putback and unget". The OP asked for how many bytes were actually written.

Comment: @yasouser The OP simply used confusing terminology. From the context it’s clear that he meant *read* (as in: read *from the file* and written to the `buffer` variable).

Answer (score 5):

Your code is both overly complicated and error-prone.

Reading in a loop and checking only for `eof` is a logic error since this will result in an infinite loop if there is an error while reading (for whatever reason).

Instead, you need to check *all* fail states of the stream, which can be done by simply checking for the `istream` object itself.

Since this is already returned by the `read` function, you can (and, indeed, should) structure any reader loop like this:

```
while (myFile.read(buffer, aBlock))
    process(buffer, aBlock);
process(buffer, myFile.gcount());
```

This is at the same time shorter, doesn’t hide bugs and is *more readable* since the check-stream-state-in-loop is an established C++ idiom.

Comment: OK, I never handled C++ files this way before. So that loop will only read one block?

Comment: @Erandros That loop will read as many blocks as there are or until the end of file is reached, or until there is an error reading the file (e.g. because the user has meanwhile deleted it, or there’s a device failure).

Comment: Unfortunately in the (normal) case that the file length is not a multiple of the blocksize, your solution leaves the final small block unprocessed. Unless you process it after the loop ends. I have tried to help the frustrated questioner here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449198/using-buffers-to-read-from-unknown-size-file/6449509#6449509) after he posted essentially the same question again because of this issue.

Comment: @Bill Yes, the processing after the loop end was kind of implied. … I didn’t really think that far ahead, to be honest; the nice thing about the above loop is that you don’t have to check `gcount` inside the loop at all, so if you hand off the actual processing to a function, then all that the above requires is one additional function call at the end. I’ll amend the answer.

Comment: Thanks after this amendment your answer now makes good sense, so +1. I have linked to it as a good alternative in the other thread.

Comment: 2 and a half years gone by. Back then I didn't see the value in the code you posted. Now I see it. It is really so much simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at [`istream::readsome`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/readsome/), which actually returns the amount of bytes read.

Comment: This function has fundamentally different semantics, however. It will merely read the current buffer associated with the stream.